# Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, messaging

**I am trying to link my app with firebase messaging services it compiled with this warning:**

*INFO: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getJavaCompile(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app*

**When I run the I get the following error:**

```
*Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`. Use the                `CompileOptions.annotationProcessorPath` property instead.*


**My app gradle content is:**
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    // Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider
    apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
    implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'

    // Preferences Dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'

}
```

**My project gradle content is:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'


        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with following setps below:

1- Remove android-apt plugin by deleting the ***line below***:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

2- Change **apt** to **implementation**

So ***apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'***

become ***implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'***

Then the app crashes after implementing the 2 steps above:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.example.com.myProject.provider.generated........Provider"**

3- I fixed this error with adding this code in app gradle file:

```
android {
.........
..........
defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
}

.....
....
}
```