# Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`. Use the `CompileOptions.annotationProcessorPath` property instead

Tags: firebase, android-studio, github, gradle

I'm cloning an android course project from GitHub, and facing a series of errors, I've manged to solve some of them till I stuck in last one, the scenario as follows:

1- error: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0. (Solved).

2- error: File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.(solved)

3-error: Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`. Use the `CompileOptions.annotationProcessorPath` property instead.

This one that I can't fix[Error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqcax.png)

and after adding this implementation (
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'), I get that error as well.

- error: This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  [Error snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhn5d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that link that has exact fix to the errors mentioned in the question.

[Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60794604/cannot-specify-processorpath-or-processor-path-via-compileoptions-compilerar)

solution.

```
Delete “apply plugin: ‘android-apt’” line from your app module build.gradle file.
(Not necessary to work) Delete “classpath ‘com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2’” from your top-level build.gradle file.
In “dependencies” section in build.gradle rename
apt ‘net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3’
to
annotationProcessor ‘net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3’
I’m using newest 26.0.2 buildToolsVersion as well as newest support libraries and everything works like a charm.
Remember to use newest gradle (4.1-all for now) and gradle plugin (3.0.0 for now). Add google repository to download newest support libraries. Sync and rebuild project. Now when you go to your manifest file, there should be no more red android:name=".provider.generated.SquawkProvider"

My top-level build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
}
dependencies {
classpath ‘com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0’

    // Google Services plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Let me know if it works.